# Environment with sub-tags

Tags: environments

Is it possible to create an environment usable in this way...?

```
\begin{myEnvironment}

\{title}[This is a title]
\{year}[2016]
\{content}[Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisci elit,
sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut
enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis
suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur.]

\end{myEnvironment}
```

...or this way...?

```
\begin{myEnvironment}

\{title} This is a title
\{year} 2016
\{content} Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisci elit,
sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut
enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis
suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur.

\end{myEnvironment}
```

...or something similar?

And if I want I can omit a field (for example `title`).

The output should be something like this (for example):

> - **Title:** This is a title
> - **Year:** 2016
>
> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisci elit, sed eiusmod
>   tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim
>   veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit
>   laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur.

Comment: Is there a problem with the more standard approach: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item \textbf{Title:} This is a title
\item \textbf{Year:} 2016
\end{itemize}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's possible and also with a friendly user level syntax.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentEnvironment{myenv}{m} % <--- choose a better name
 {
  % process the keys
  \keys_set:nn { myenv } { #1 }
  % print them
  \par\addvspace{\topsep}
  \noindent\makebox[4em][l]{\textbullet\ \textbf{Title:}}~\l_myenv_title_tl
  \\*
  \noindent\makebox[4em][l]{\textbullet\ \textbf{Year:}}~\l_myenv_year_tl
  \\*
  \ignorespaces
 }
 {
  \par\addvspace{\topsep}
 }

% define the keys
\keys_define:nn { myenv }
 {
  title .tl_set:N = \l_myenv_title_tl,
  year  .tl_set:N = \l_myenv_year_tl,
  title .value_required:n = true,
  year  .value_required:n = true,
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{myenv}{
  title = This is a title,
  year  = 2016,
}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisci elit, 
sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna
aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem
ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea
commodi consequatur.
\end{myenv}

\end{document}
```

[image]